# Only Output Rule Alerts to Suricata EVE

Tags: json, network-security, suricata

I have Suricata setup as HIDS on a couple of lab instances, and wrote some sample rules to alert on custom User-Headers and internal IPs I can easily trigger for purpose of teaching someone how to use Suricata.

For an advanced use case, I want to output the EVE JSON file somewhere downstream for eventual data analytics and BI use cases.

For that purpose, I want to drop the "noise" from EVE, or have a way for the fast.log to be output in JSON.

For instance, this is what I would consider "noise" as I want to just see triggered

```
,"event_type":"stats","stats":{"uptime":168,"capture":{"kernel_packets":313,"kernel_drops":0,"errors":0},"decoder":{"pkts":313,"bytes":68519,"invalid":0,"ipv4":305,"ipv6":0,"ethernet":313,"r$
{"timestamp":"2019-08-13T14:29:09.058698+0000","event_type":"stats","stats":{"uptime":176,"capture":{"kernel_packets":313,"kernel_drops":0,"errors":0},"decoder":{"pkts":313,"bytes":68519,"invalid":0,"ipv4":305,"ipv6":0,"ethernet":313,"r$
{"timestamp":"2019-08-13T14:29:17.059944+0000","event_type":"stats","stats":{"uptime":184,"capture":{"kernel_packets":313,"kernel_drops":0,"errors":0},"decoder":{"pkts":313,"bytes":68519,"invalid":0,"ipv4":305,"ipv6":0,"ethernet":313,"r$
```

I would only want to see stuff like this from fast.log
`[**] [1:200002:6] ET USER_AGENTS Suspicious User Agent (BlackSun) [**] [Classification: A Network Trojan was detected] [Priority: 1] {TCP}`

So is there a way to get only the Alerts in EVE, or a way to transform Fast.log into JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer for myself again.

On Line 60 in the YAML, there is a value you can set to "No" for stats - that will eliminate probably 80% of the noise you have. You can go further an eliminate metadata for DNS, TLS, TCP, HTTP, etc. to further reduce your log file if needed.

Comment: But it still has noise.

Comment: You can transform fast.log into json using lua script.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone out there who could find this question and is looking for something similar, it is actually possible to split Suricata EVE output into different JSON files, so one could set-up alert events to go to a alert.json file, for instance, then stats go to a different one, and application layer protocol ones to a third file, so one wouldn't have so much noise, but still find the more complete output that EVE offers, in case they wanted to follow up on anything unusual.

In order to do that in the suricata.yaml file, outputs section, do something like:

```yaml
outputs:
  - eve-log:
      enabled: yes
      filename: eve-alerts.json
      types:
        - alert
```

This would ensure that you get all the useful info that the EVE log has to offer, without having the noise from unwanted events.

This suricata verify test showcases how this could be done: https://github.com/OISF/suricata-verify/blob/master/tests/output-multi-eve/suricata.yaml